# How to hide certain divs as browser window shrinks?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a business requirement to hide divs as the screen collapses. For example, I have a toolbar loaded with divs in which some divs are buttons containing text and an icon. Other div buttons have only an icon, no text. For the div/buttons that contain both text and an icon, if the browser window becomes narrower than the width of the toolbar, I need all text inside div-buttons to hide/collapse, leaving only the icon. And then if the browser window becomes larger again--large enough to accommodate the full toolbar--I need the text inside the div-buttons to expand/reappear.

EXAMPLE - original toolbar:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [X] Button 1     [X] Button 2    [X]   [X] Button 4
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EXAMPLE - collapsed toolbar:

```
--------------------------------
 [X]  [X]  [X]  [X] 
--------------------------------
```

NOTE: [X] represents an image icon.

I can probably figure out some jquery to do this all dynamically, but that seems error prone and could become a rat hole. Is there a CSS approach to this? Perhaps something in which a div (either my outer toolbar div or the inner button-divs) realizes it's out of space, and triggers some kind of style or class at that point?

**Important: I can't know the width of the toolbar in advance, it's dynamic and dependent on server events and user settings. Therefore I don't think CSS media queries will solve this.**

Am I stuck with a jquery solution?

Comment: read up on css media queries

Comment: Google `css media query`

Comment: css media queries are the best.  Otherwise jQuery window resize function.

Comment: I know about media queries, but those rely on knowing the width of my toolbar in advance -- which I don't, it's dynamic based on server-side things. I'll update my post, I should have mentioned that.